# Can i create depth or bump maps from this image without sculpting or modeling?

Tags: modeling, height-map, bump

Is there a way for me to create the height or bump map of the design on this door without modeling or sculpting it or maybe a trim sheet?.[image]

Comment: I'm confident i could sculpt it just being lazy lol. Just want to focus on bigger models and if i could get his done quick and easy i'd like to do that and like i said focus on larger more time consuming models i need.

Comment: Not an ideal image for it.. but you could check out  Bounding Box's [Materialize](http://www.boundingboxsoftware.com/materialize/index.php)

Answer (score 1):

There is a website called CrazyBump which converts 2d images to 3d displacement maps its called CrazyBump! here's the website link to go check it out https://cpetry.github.io/NormalMap-Online/

Comment: yes, is correct